# Use NSPredicate to filter by object attribute

Tags: iphone, array-filter

I have a mutable array of custom objects. I want to filter that array by attribute of the object, for example *myObject.attributeOne*.

How can I create the NSPredicate to use with

```
[myArrayOfObjects filterUsingPredicate:<the_predicate>]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it in this way:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FriendStatus == 1"];

NSMutableArray *filtered = [MessageArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```