# Remove certain objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I have an `NSMutableArray` of objects which are of `AdDetail` class that hold a few properties (for eg. adId, adTitle, adPrice... etc). I want to remove only those objects which have `adID = 0`. How can I do that ?

Comment: use predicate to filter the list/array..

Comment: There are many posts and samples to work out filtering array using NSPredicate.. some of below posts will help u.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207050/searching-filtering-a-custom-class-array-with-a-nspredicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386079/use-nspredicate-to-filter-by-object-attribute

Comment: why is everybody down-voting this question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps something more elegant would suffice?

```
[array removeObjectsInArray:[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"adID == 0"]]];
```

Comment: +1 I liked this one :)

Comment: can I negate this?(`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"adID != 0"]`)

Comment: Sure thing :] That would filter the array to remove objects where your adID is not equal to zero.

Comment: one more thing adID is of class `NSInteger` due to that my app is crashing with `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key adID.`

Comment: Is your `AdDetail` object a subclass of `NSManagedObject`? Perhaps changing your `NSInteger` to an `NSNumber` would be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Using predicate

```
NSArray *filtered=[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(adId == 0)"]];
```

Using fastEnumeration:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray=[NSMutableArray new];
for(AdDetail adDetailObj in array){
    if(![[adDetailObj adId] isEqualToString:@"0"]){ //if these are strings, if NSInteger then directly compare using ==
       newArray[newArray.count]=adDetailObj;
   }
}
```

Now `newArray` contains all objects other than `id=0`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:yourArray];

for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.count; i++)
{
     AdDetail *obj = (AdDetail *)[yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
     if (obj.adID == 0)
         [newArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
yourArray = [newArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I think because I didn't put open and close bracket after if ;-)

Comment: you are removing objects from the array while iterating, this will cause an error

Comment: @tkanzakic: I am not removing while iterating :p

Comment: @tkanzakic: good point, Rushi: you have done edit with your answer but still it will cause an error..

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i < myArray.count; i++)
{
  myClass = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
  if([myClass.adID isEqualtoString:"0"])// if it it int/NSInteger the write myClass.adID==0
  {
            [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
      i--;
  }
}
```

Comment: you are removing objects from the array while iterating, this will cause an error

Answer (score 1):

Use following code :

```
int count = array.count;
for(i=0;i<count;i++){

     ADetail *adetail = [array objectAtIndex:i];
     if(adetail.adID = 0){

         [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
          i--;

     }
     count = array.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
predicate = @"adID == 0";
newArray = [theArray filterUsingPredicate:aPredicate]
```